# BackHandler is getting called from all pages

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I have written following function for handling back button press:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert('Hold on!', 'Are you sure you want to Logout?', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => null,
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      { text: 'YES', onPress: logout },
    ]);
    return true;
  };

  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    'hardwareBackPress',
    backAction
  );

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, []);
```

This is my `logout` function:

```js
async function logout() {
  setLoginState(true);
  const user1 = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const token1 = user1.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
  console.log('toekn 1  ' + token1);
  try {
    await Auth.signOut();
    setLoginState(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    setLoginState(false);
  }
  {
    loginState ? <Loader /> : console.log('None');
  }

  props.navigation.navigate('Login');
}
```

The problem is that when I am pressing the back button on some other page, even then the `backAction` function is getting called. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To handle Back press, I would suggest you to follow these steps:-

Create a Folder Called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

Inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useBackHandler.js`

Your `useBackHandler.js` should look like this

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

export function useBackHandler(handler) {
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handler);

    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handler);
  }, [handler]);
}
```

Now, to use this handler what you need to do is shown below.

```js
useBackHandler(() => {
  if (someCondition) {
    // Handle Backpress here
    return true;
  }
  // Let Backpress behave as default
  return false;
});
```

So in your case, you should then use it like this

```js
useBackHandler(() => {
  Alert.alert('Hold on!', 'Are you sure you want to Logout?', [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => null,
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    { text: 'YES', onPress: logout },
  ]);
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the removing of Listener in screens; remove it in each screen then try again. See the code below:

```
  return () =>
     remove here
   })
```